# Java - SQL - Mostrar datos en un formulario Java Swing

Tags: java, sql

Tengo una aplicación de venta de vehículos. En la **base de datos MySQL** tengo vehículos comprados (por clientes) y vehículos aún no comprados (disponibles para comprar).

En la base de datos distingo las tablas: **vehículos y vehículos_compra.**

Organigrama de la base de datos | Modelo E-R: https://s23.postimg.org/cbzwk6auj/bbdd_esquema_ER.png

Resulta que en un `JFrame` o aplicación Java o Java Swing muestro una ficha técnica de los vehículos que tengo en la tabla vehículos_compra (tanto los comprados como los no comprados).

Imagen de vehículos comprados: https://s30.postimg.org/lirrjso01/comprado.png

Imagen de vehículos no comprados: https://s24.postimg.org/u9qoyenmd/no_comprado.png

Como podéis ver me salta el error: "`java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.`", esto se debe a que intenta cargar los datos del cliente pero al no estar comprado ese vehículo no existen y no se pueden cargar.

¿Cómo podría dejarlos en "null" esos datos del cliente y cargar los del vehículo?

Cualquier duda estoy dispuesto a comentarla. Os dejo código para que os sea más útil.

Código:

```
public static ArrayList ficha_tecnica_compra() {
        //Al ser la ficha técnica sólo de un bastidor, guardamos los datos en un ArrayList.
        ArrayList<String> bastidores = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los bastidores.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_bastidores = "SELECT bastidor FROM vehiculos_compra;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_bastidores);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS BASTIDORES: Mostramos todos bastidores de la tabla 'vehiculos_compra'.\n");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String bastidor = rs.getString("bastidor");
                bastidores.add(bastidor);
                i++;
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bastidores;
    }

public static Object[] datos_de_un_bastidor_compra(String bastidor) {
        //Creamos un objeto "v" de 11 valores: marca, modelo, matricula, fecha_v_compra, nombre, apellidos, dni, tlf_contacto, direccion, ciudad, email.
        Object[] v = new Object[11];
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los datos del "vehiculos_compra" de un bastidor.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_de_un_bastidor = "SELECT v.marca, v.modelo, v.matricula, c.*, vc.fecha_v_compra, m.nombre \n" +
                                             "FROM clientes_compra AS cc, vehiculos AS v, vehiculos_compra AS vc, clientes AS c, marca AS m\n" +
                                             "WHERE cc.ID_VEHICULO='" + bastidor + "' AND v.bastidor=cc.ID_VEHICULO AND c.DNI=cc.DNI AND m.ID=v.marca;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_de_un_bastidor);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA DATOS: Datos de un bastidor en concreto.\n");
            rs.next();
            //Guardamos los valores extraidos de la consulta en cada tipo de dato específico (variables).
            String marca = rs.getString("m.nombre");
            String modelo = rs.getString("modelo");
            String matricula = rs.getString("matricula");
            Date fecha_v_compra = rs.getDate("fecha_v_compra");
            String nombre = rs.getString("c.nombre");
            String apellidos = rs.getString("apellidos");
            String dni = rs.getString("dni");
            String tlf_contacto = rs.getString("tlf_contacto");
            String direccion = rs.getString("direccion");
            String ciudad = rs.getString("ciudad");
            String email = rs.getString("email");
            //Volcamos esas variables en el objeto "v".
            v[0] = marca;
            v[1] = modelo;
            v[2] = matricula;
            v[3] = fecha_v_compra;
            v[4] = nombre;
            v[5] = apellidos;
            v[6] = dni;
            v[7] = tlf_contacto;
            v[8] = direccion;
            v[9] = ciudad;
            v[10] = email;
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Devolvemos el objeto "v".
        return v;
    }
```

Al cambiar de bastidor (los cargo en un combobox, se me actualizan los restantes datos de ese bastidor, es la clave primaria de todas las tablas). Por eso la siguiente función (evento):

```
private void jComboBox_bastidorItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                    
        //Recogemos en la variable "bastidor" el valor seleccionado en el combobox con el método "getSelectedItem()".
        String bastidor = (String) jComboBox_bastidor.getSelectedItem();
        //Guardamos en un objecto "v" los datos del bastidor gracias a la función "Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_compra(bastidor);".
        Object[] v = Conexiones.datos_de_un_bastidor_compra(bastidor);
        //Datos del coche --> Otorgamos a los campos jTextField los valores recogidos en el "Object[] v".
        textfield_marca.setText(String.valueOf(v[0]));
        textfield_marca.setEditable(false);
        textfield_modelo.setText(String.valueOf(v[1]));
        textfield_modelo.setEditable(false);
        textfield_matricula.setText(String.valueOf(v[2]));
        textfield_matricula.setEditable(false);
        textfield_fechacompra.setText(String.valueOf(v[3]));
        textfield_fechacompra.setEditable(false);
        //Datos del cliente --> Otorgamos a los campos jTextField los valores recogidos en el "Object[] v".
        textfield_nombre.setText(String.valueOf(v[4]));
        textfield_nombre.setEditable(false);
        textfield_apellidos.setText(String.valueOf(v[5]));
        textfield_apellidos.setEditable(false);
        textfield_DNI.setText(String.valueOf(v[6]));
        textfield_DNI.setEditable(false);
        textfield_tlf_contacto.setText(String.valueOf(v[7]));
        textfield_tlf_contacto.setEditable(false);
        textfield_direccion.setText(String.valueOf(v[8]));
        textfield_direccion.setEditable(false);
        textfield_ciudad.setText(String.valueOf(v[9]));
        textfield_ciudad.setEditable(false);
        textfield_email.setText(String.valueOf(v[10]));
        textfield_email.setEditable(false);
        //Imagen del coche.
        label_foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon("..\\imagenes\\"+String.valueOf(v[1])+".png"));
    }
```

Comment: Hola omaza. La pregunta está escrita asumiendo que conocemos ya muchos detalles de tu aplicación, pero obviamente, no es el caso. Detalles que faltan: el stack trace completo del error, descripción de tus tablas en la base de datos y la relación entre ellas, ejemplo de datos. Nota aparte, te sugiero de usar `PreparedStatement` para evitar concatenar los valores directamente en tu consulta. También, trata de usar el patrón `try-with-resources` para manejar el cierre de la conexión, statement y resultset.

Comment: Os dejo el modelo entidad relación de la base de datos para que podais echar un ojo.

Comment: .¿alguna idea?.

Comment: Normalmente este tipo de preguntas poco especificas en las que hay que buscar entre mucho código no se les presta tanta atención como si acotas al máximo tu problema. Deberías modificarla para hacerla atractiva antes que tirar de ella con comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

En el método datos_de_un_bastidor_compra cambia:

```
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_de_un_bastidor);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA DATOS: Datos de un bastidor en concreto.\n");
            rs.next();
            //Guardamos los valores extraidos de la consulta en cada tipo de dato específico (variables).
            String marca = rs.getString("m.nombre");
```

por

```
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_de_un_bastidor);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA DATOS: Datos de un bastidor en concreto.\n");
            if (rs.next()){
                //Guardamos los valores extraidos de la consulta en cada tipo de dato específico (variables).
                String marca = rs.getString("m.nombre");
               ...
            }
```

Estás accediendo al retorno de la consulta sin tener en cuenta si hay o no resultados, y de ahí el error.